# Layerslider deeplink issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow, deep-linking

I have an issue with an external link to a specific layerslider slide (html version, NOT wordpress).

This is the web page:

http://www.jeeltcraft.com/sogea/HTML/slider.html

I asked in the support forum and they told me to use this javasript:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#slider').layerSlider(2);"> Some text </a>
```

Which of course you can find in the layerslider documentation page:

http://www.docs.purethemes.net/sukces/layerslider/documentation/documentation.html#deeplinking

but I'm a total newbie about javascript and I cannot get the link working, the worse part is.. I can't understand how this javascript refers to the layername I put in the style"deeplink: layername;" of the layer I want to link; i guess it uses an index number and in the docu you can see that maybe index numbers have to be written on a variable...

The javascript link is located on the "primary-menu" element of the first page i linked, can someone please help me?

Any help will be appreciated gratefully

Answer (score 0):

you can use html) Just write `<p><a href="http://your_link" target="_blank"><img src="/image_part/image.jpg" border="0" alt="" /></a></p>`    PS. From Russia

Answer (score -1):

If you never got this figured out it is because of the $

I ended up using jQuery in place of $ and changed javascript:void(0); to only javascript:; and it works as expected.